# Mysql, automate copy data database to temporary database

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have a case like this:

- I have 2 database on 1 server, say it db1 and db2
- db2 will be a copy of db1
- data from db1 copied automatically to db2
- data from db2 will not sync with db1 (db2 just a test database)

Any idea's to accomplish this? database can't be restart since it crucial (which editing my.cnf solution probably doesn't fit in this situation)

Thanks

Comment: Do you need this to be copied update by update or is "once a day" or something ok?

Answer (score 0):

Take dump of database from db1 and restore it to db2. write a script to automate it and run it from cron according to interval you have set.